# How does Grease Pencil handle object depth in the viewport?

Tags: grease-pencil

In this pic from the side, the objects can be seen as they are correctly ordered from front to back
[image: objects from side]

This is the camera view.  Note the front object from the previous pic is now hidden behind another object.
[image: objects from front]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

In Grease Pencil Object Properties, there is a Stroke Depth Order dropdown. [image]